# How do I get my icon to display on the same line as my rectangle?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the black x mark to display on the same line as the second green rectangle. I tried using display: inline, but it still won't show up on the same line. Can someone help please?

http://jsfiddle.net/a4Cg4/1/

Comment: Can I say that your HTML and CSS are just weird to me?

Comment: It looks so but not that much imho, except the `align` attribute and the lack of alt attribute on an image that obviously bring some meaning. There are many divs but it could be a stripped down version of some huge code or be OOCSS-like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML code, moving the mark inside the element where it'll float is mandatory, if I understood what you want to achieve.

Then you use deprecated attribute `align="center"` and it complicates everything when trying to position the mark... Nonetheless here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/a4Cg4/5/
(modified CSS is at the top, first and second rule)

Unrelated to your problem but still: every HTML img needs an alt attribute, even if it's empty for decorative images (or when context like surrounding text already says what the image represent). I added it to the HTML code.